# mysql left outer join exclude

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables '`conta`' and '`details`' and both the tables have null values and data in different case

```
conta
id  col1  col2  col3  col4
1  Hi  Bye  See YOU  
2  Hello  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)

details

id  new_column1  new_column2  new_column3
1  bye  see  you
```

I want to apply join based on `col2=new_column1 and col3 = new_column2 and col4 = new_column3` and get the values that are present in `conta` and not in `details`, so my output will be

```
conta
id  col1  col2  col3  col4
2  hello  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)
```

But somehow i am unable to do so. I wrote below query, but its simply not resulting me the values i want.

```
SELECT `id`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4` FROM `conta`
WHERE LOWER(`col2`) + LOWER(`col3`) + LOWER(`col4`) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(`new_column1`) + LOWER(`new_column2`) + LOWER(`new_column3`))
 FROM `details`);
```

It simply give me no results! in the display

Any help?

**Edit:** I tried below query as suggested by @Uueerdo and it isn't giving me what i want.

```
SELECT conta.id,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4` FROM `conta`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `details`
ON ((conta.col2 IS NULL AND details.new_column1 IS NULL) 
    OR (LOWER(conta.col2) = LOWER(details.new_column1)))
AND ((conta.col3 IS NULL AND details.new_column2 IS NULL) 
    OR (LOWER(conta.col3) = LOWER(details.new_column2)))
AND ((conta.col4 IS NULL AND details.new_column3 IS NULL) 
    OR (LOWER(conta.col4) = LOWER(details.new_column3)))
WHERE details.id IS NULL
```

In the output in `col2` i see a value '*Operations*' which is also present in `new_column1` in `details` table. This means it shouldn't be present in the output as i am trying to apply **left outer join exclude** I even tried using LEFT JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN and it isn't working either

**Edit2**: I found the solution. the query works and does the job. Exept that i had to run a command to replace all blank cells in the columns where i am applying join to NULL values.

Comment: I think you need to clean up your sample data a bit; it looks like you have 6 values in 5 fields for the first row.

Comment: My bad! I just corrected this. I am actually curious to know why its not giving me the results i want. I mean what is wrong with my query.

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using a `SELECT .... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON conditions WHERE b.id IS NULL` style of query; null comparisons are a little different (and can be handled join conditions).

For example these evaluate to NULL, which is not true, which is false:

- NULL = NULL
- NULL IN (NULL)

But you can do things like this to compare nulls more easily:

- ISNULL(a, x) = ISNULL(b, x)
- (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL)

So you're join condition can be something like:

```
[...]
ON ((conta.col2 IS NULL AND details.new_column1 IS NULL) 
    OR (LOWER(conta.col2) = LOWER(details.new_column1)))
AND ((conta.col3 IS NULL AND details.new_column2 IS NULL) 
    OR (LOWER(conta.col3) = LOWER(details.new_column2)))
[and so on...]
WHERE details.id IS NULL
```

This assumes `details` has some sort of non-null row identification field that can used to reliably determine if there was a match or not.

---

Edit: The precise problem with your current query (aside from the null issues I previously outlined) is that `+` is not concatenation in MySQL, it is addition. With the data you've shown both `LOWER(col2) + LOWER(col3) + LOWER(col4)` and `LOWER(new_column1) + LOWER(new_column2) + LOWER(new_column3)` with yield `0` for the rows without NULL values in them. You would need to use the `CONCAT()` function to do the operation instead; but I'd discourage it because `CONCAT('abc', 'def', '')` is equal to `CONCAT('ab', 'cd', 'ef')`.

Sidenote: `DISTINCT` is not a function, the `()` will have no effect (*other than that they would cause a problem if they contained more than one result field*).

---

You can keep your general format, and the aforementioned null issues, by a simple change with this format : `WHERE (a, b, c) IN (SELECT a, b, c FROM ....`

Comment: I went through your suggestions and it isn't working. i have added my syntax and the concern in the edit to my post

Comment: Never mind, i found the issue. there are some cells which have blanks in addition to NULL value. your solution is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left join, then test for a null in the 2nd table to find the rows in the first table that didn't match any rows in the 2nd table.

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`,
    a.`col1`,
    a.`col2`,
    a.`col3`,
    a.`col4` 
FROM `conta` a
LEFT JOIN `details` b
ON a.`col2` like b.`new_column1`
    AND a.`col3` like b.`new_column2`
    AND a.`col4` like b.`new_column3`
WHERE b.`id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `EXISTS` operator to create an anti-semi join. Please take a look at this link: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php

Example Query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4
FROM conta
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM details
    WHERE conta.col2 LIKE details.new_column1
        AND conta.col3 LIKE details.new_column2
        AND conta.col4 LIKE details.new_column3
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem Solution Is inner join your (contact table) with (details table)
and get (contact.*) All columns where Contact.col1 !=details.new_column1

here is a query

```
Select conta.* from conta inner join details on conta.col1!=details.new_column1
```

You Can And More Where column in inner join

Comment: If You have Any Problem Comment Please

Comment: Your query is getting all the `conta` where there is something that doesn't match in `details`; as opposed to the `conta` that do not have a match in `details`. Also, your first sentence doesn't make much sense; I'd chalk it up to translation issues but can't figure out why the `contact.*` should even be mentioned.